# Another conjecture on sum $A+B=C$

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory

> Could You give your ideas, your comment, or a referen for a conjecture as follows:

Consider $A, B, C$ be three positive integers numbers. By [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) we write:

$A=a_1^{x_1}a_2^{x_2}...a_n^{x_n}$,

$B=b_1^{y_1}b_2^{y_2}...b_m^{y_m}$,

$C=c_1^{z_1}c_2^{z_2}...c_k^{z_k}$

Let $N=\min\{x_i, y_j, z_h \}$ where $1 \le i \le n,  1\ \le j \le m, 1\le h \le k$

> For a positive integer $N_0 \ge 3$, there exist only finitely many triples $(A, B, C)$ of coprime positive integers, with $A+B=C$, such that: $N \ge N_0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counter Example: $271^3+2^3\cdot 3^5\cdot 73^3 = 919^3$

Comment: See also the Mathoverflow answer to the parallel question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273607/another-conjecture-on-sum-ab-c/273608#273608

Comment: Did you use computer to find this example?